# Calculation of real numbers in base 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone help me how to calculate real numbers in base 7? My program doesn't work correct.

For example, this is my input:

```
exp = '25.255-35.33'
```

Here i am separating the numbers of left and right side of '-':

```
if '-' in exp:
    left,right = exp.split('-')
    if float(left) > float(right):
        an_integer = float(left) - float(right)
    else:
        #here i am separating the numbers again
        a = str(float(left)).split('.')
        b = str(float(right)).split('.')
```

Here i am working with the integers:

```
        a1 = [*map(int,str(a[0]))]
        b1 = [*map(int,str(b[0]))]
        a1 = a1[::-1]
        b1 = b1[::-1]
        size = max(len(a1), len(b1))
        a1 += [0] * (size - len(a1))
        b1 += [0] * (size - len(b1))
        overflow = 0
        result = []
        for obj in zip(a1, b1):
            value = obj[1] - obj[0] - overflow
            overflow = value // 7 
            result.append(value % 7) 
        result = result[::-1]
```

Here i am working with the decimals and then i am printing my result:

```
        #here i am working with the decimals
        left1 = [*map(int,str(a[1]))]
        left2 = [*map(int,str(b[1]))]
        size = max(len(left1), len(left2))
        left1 += [0] * (size - len(left1))
        left2 += [0] * (size - len(left2))
        left1 = left1[::-1]
        left2 = left2[::-1]
        overflow2 = 0
        result2 = []
        for obj in zip(left1, left2):
            value2 = obj[1] - obj[0] - overflow2
            overflow2 = value2 // 7
            result2.append(value2%7) 
        result2 = result2[::-1]
        result2 = list(result2)
        result2.insert(0,'.')
        strings = [str(i) for i in result]
        a_string = ''. join(strings)
        an_integer = int(a_string)
        an_integer = an_integer * (-1)
        an_integer = list(str(an_integer))
        an_integer.extend(result2)
        an_integer = [str(i) for i in an_integer]
    an_integer =''.join(an_integer)
    print(an_integer)
```

For example, if i input: 25.255 - 35.33, the result should be -10.042,but i am getting -10.262
P.S. If you put your numbers,they should be in 7th number system
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? "My program doesn't work very well." is not a practical problem description. Please see the [ask] help page how to best help us help you; strongly consider to [edit] your question to add a [mcve].

Comment: "My program doesn't work correct." – how so? Does it throw an error? Does it provide incorrect results? If so, which results do you get and which did you expect instead?

Comment: _What_ is the "7th number system"? Do you mean base 7? The expected result is not base 7, so something else.

Comment: @Spizzy Do you need base-7 system computations for some specific reason? Because it is much easier to convert input numbers from base-7 to regular python ints or floats, then do all operations with built-in functions, and convert final result back to base-7 for output. Or you have some homework assignment to implement all arithmetics from scratch by hand strictly in base-7?

Comment: Are you saying that the input data is in base 7 and you want to express the result in base 7? Or is input in some other base and you just want the output expressed in base 7?

Comment: The input is in base 7 and i need to implement all arithmetics from scratch by hand strictly in base-7.(its my homework)

Comment: @aneriod I edited the question to say *base 7* instead because the intent was evident from the code (repeated `div` and `mod` by 7). Please cut questioners whose first language is not English a bit of slack.